# Could not load -ipad images in Universal app

Tags: ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I am creating a universal ios 2D game using cocos2d. I have few images with naming convention as imageName-ipad.png but the app is not able to load this image when i try to load using following line.

```
coinItem =[CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"coins.png" selectedImage:@"coins.png" target:self selector:@selector(coinsSelected:)];
```

Where coinItem is CCMenuItem type.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmed from Cocos2d forum that -ipad support is not in version 1.0.1 of Cocos2d. So i modified CCFileUtils.m - the getDoubleResolutionImage method to implement support for ipad.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `imageName~ipad.png`
And for the new iPad `imageName@2x~ipad.png`

Comment: Check your ccDirector scale and UIScreen scale if they mismatch, probably this is the cause. Otherwise CCMenu shouldn't have problem with the ~ipad...

Comment: Graver, both contentScaleFector of CCDirector and UIScreen scale are 1.00.

Comment: Hmm, not sure why isn't working, but you can always check if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) and if the scale factor is 1.00 or 2.00 and determine the appropriate picture to load...